# The conference started tomorrow

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

I heard when someone told "The conference started tomorrow" so my question is: is it correct grammatical and acceptible? If yes when I can use it?

Comment: I reckon it's *grammatically* correct as everything is in the right place but it's *semantically* dubious because tomorrow can surely never be in the past.

Comment: Conjugate 'to start' ... if this makes no sense to you post your question on the ELL site.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please [edit] your post to include the precise context in which you heard this expression. It could be acceptable, for example, if it reflects a change in schedule: *The conference started tomorrow according to the approved agenda, but because of the blizzard, the opening session now takes place on Friday*. Or, there might be even more contrived scenarios involving time zone differences or some such. Without knowing more details about what was said and when, we cannot say for certain whether it was an error, a grammatical but awkward usage, or deliberate.

Answer (score 2):

There are contexts where a combination of past tense with a future time-reference  would be idiomatic and grammatical, as choster remarks in the comment. Consider the following imaginary conversation.

> Bob: I'm looking forward to the conference next week.
>    Mike: It's not next week! It's tomorrow.
>    Bob: Really? When I checked the brochure it **started next week**.

This would be an elliptical form of so-called 'reported speech'.

It's possible you heard something analogous.

Answer (score -3):

It's definitely incorrect. There is a reason we use tenses. We cannot use the simple past tense for future events.

"The conference will start tomorrow" makes sense.

If you're referring to an event from the past that started the next day, you can say simply that.

"The conference started the next day."

Comment: Answers that fail to take into account possible context make me tense.

Comment: Please do not include generic website 'recommendations' and other superfluous comments in your answers. I have amended your answer to remove those.